# Easier way to do column division in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 16 columns. I would like to divide each `count` column by its respective `dc(uid)` column.

```
+------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| count: interaction_eis | count: interaction_eis_reply | count: interaction_match | count: interaction_single_message_ | count: interaction_single_message_1 | count: interaction_yes | count: revenue_sale | dc(uid): interaction_eis | dc(uid): interaction_eis_reply | dc(uid): interaction_match | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_ | dc(uid): interaction_single_message_1 | dc(uid): interaction_yes | dc(uid): revenue_sale |
+------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I know that I can do this:

```
pre_purch_m['interaction_eis_rate'] = pre_purch_m['count: interaction_eis'] / pre_purch_m['dc(uid): interaction_eis']
pre_purch_m['interaction_eis_reply_rate'] = pre_purch_m['count: interaction_eis_reply'] / pre_purch_m['dc(uid): interaction_eis_reply']
```

But it seems redundant and laborious to do this 8 times.

Is there a pandas function or paradigm to accomplish something like this in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Well your columns seem to be named in a consistent manner so it's trivial to just pass a list of the column suffixes to use to perform the division with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your columns are consistent. Here's one approach.

Get the columns from dataframe `df`.

```
cols = df.columns
```

Get the unique columns by striping away `count:` and `dc(uid):` and taking the unique list.

```
uniq_cols = list(set([x.split(': ')[1] for x in cols]))
```

Now, loop through creating the new columns.

```
for col in uniq_cols:
    df[col + '_rate'] = df['count: ' + col] / df['dc(uid): ' + col]
```

And, it would have been much easier if the dataframe was populated initially by storing these `uniq_cols`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: "And, it would have been much easier if the dataframe was populated initially by storing these uniq_cols."

Comment: Did the column names come directly from the file? Or, did you rename them? In the later case, you could use that list in place of `uni_cols`, makes sense?

Comment: They came directly from the file.

Comment: Ok, this method should work. I can't think of any other way unless you want to hard-code the names of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

The 16 columns are contiguous so one way to do this:

```
 newdF = df[range(8)]/df[range(8, 16)].values
```

Use the `.values` to prevent reindexing issues.

Then rename the columns:

```
newdF.rename(columns = lambda x : x.replace(x, x[6:] + '_rate'), inplace='True')
```